# send email with device information using Intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, email, android-intent

I want to send email to a specific email address when user click to an email address but the email field is blank when I click on send

```
String deviceInfo="Device Info:";
    deviceInfo += "\n OS Version: " + System.getProperty("os.version") + "(" + android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL + ")";
    deviceInfo += "\n OS API Level: " + android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    deviceInfo += "\n Device: " + android.os.Build.DEVICE;
    deviceInfo += "\n Model (and Product): " + android.os.Build.MODEL + " ("+ android.os.Build.PRODUCT + ")";

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "example@gamil.com");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, deviceInfo);
    if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(emailIntent);
    }
```

Comment: None of those extras are documented for `ACTION_SENDTO`, so there is no requirement for any app to support them. Use `ACTION_SEND` if you want to use those extras.

Comment: why all data is send other than the email address

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add mimeType to the intent and  put the mail id in an array

```
 Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
 emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
 emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"example@gamil.com"});
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, deviceInfo);
 if (emailIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
       startActivity(emailIntent);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the below method:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("mailto:%s", "example@gamil.com")));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, deviceInfo);
```

Comment: not working only email auto-fill rest subject and body of email is empty